# GNURadio How to see internal doxygen docs from cloned repo?

Tags: doxygen, gnuradio

I cloned the GNURadio repository and I want to be able to view the doxygen documentation in the repo because the stuff online is severely out of date. Is it something where I can click on a top level file and view the docs in a browser? I guess I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the installation wiki, here: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR

In section "From Source", I think that you can add:

```
-DENABLE_DEFAULT=OFF  -DENABLE_GR_DOXYGEN=ON
```

to your `cmake` command in order to build just the documentation.

`-DENABLE_DEFAULT=OFF`: no default components

`-DENABLE_GR_DOXYGEN=ON:` add doxygen documentation component to the build process

Then, after `make`, find the documentation in html format here:
`gnuradio/build/docs/doxygen/html/index.html`

No need to `make install`

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that helps a ton! As a side note, I'm not finding anything no there about OOT modules. Would you happen to know where in the docs something about would be located?